# Trying to get the index of a value in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays, one of which is in an autocomplete dropdown list.  As an item is selected, I would like find its index in the array so that I can use said index in the other two arrays.

Is there a simple solution where I can feed an array function a value (i.e. Texas) and get its index number?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [`array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.
By feeeding the search string(or any search item) as parameter, it will return the index of that item in the array.

**P.S:** *Remember that array indexes start from `0` and end with `array length-1`*.

```js
//and you're getting the  selected value
function GetSelectedItem(el) {
  var e = document.getElementById(el);
  var city = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
  var cities = ["Paris", "Adelaide", "Texas", "London", "New York"];
  var city_index = cities.indexOf(city);
  console.log(city_index);
}
```

```html
<!--If you have a dropdown list that looks something like:-->
<select id="cityList">
  <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
  <option value="Dallas" selected="selected">Dallas</option>
  <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
</select>
<button onClick="GetSelectedItem('cityList');">Get Selected Item</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but am unable to get the index to get the text.  A, building off the code from [link]https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp since my knowledge of JavaScript is beginner level.

Comment: Doh!  Got it... x[currentFocus].textContent;

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point for this type of problem is the [MDN page for the prototype of the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).

Look down the list of methods and see if there is anything which sounds promising.

In this case: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
const places = [ "Victoria", "Texas", "Berkshire" ];
console.log( places.indexOf("Texas") );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) of the Array:

```
['Florida', 'California', 'Texas'].indexOf('Texas') // => 2
```

But if you're talking about autocomplete, probably the callback that calls on item select will return the item and its index. It depends on package you use for autocomplete.

Using it's callback will be better, because you won't need to iterate the array again to find the index of the selected item.